# How to avoid escaping custom Grafana variable?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

My Grafana dashboard shows statistics for some Elastic documents. Some of these documents have the attribute `important_details`, some don't. I want to create a "Has important details: Yes/No/All" filter.

What I did was I created a new `has_important_details` variable, type "Custom", with the following options:

```
Yes : _exists_:important_details, No : NOT _exists_:important_details
```

Then, I'm editing the panel and add `$has_important_details` to the Query field.

This doesn't work, and the reason seems to be that instead of `_exists_:important_details`, it actually sends the query

```
_exists_\\:important_details
```

and likewise

```
NOT\\ _exists_\\:important_details
```

for the opposite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it out myself after all. Instead of `$has_important_details`, the Query field should be `${has_important_details:raw}`.